# Laravel : push job to failed table

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

Is there any way or method to push a job to `failed_jobs` table?
I know i may use `tries` option but i'm looking for a solution to set this option only for specific jobs not all jobs

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but I write if this is help any other developer
I used Redis queue in Laravel before and its pushing job into failed table when you throw an exception

for example :
throw new \Exception("cause of error or etc..");

you can use tries for your specific job with defining it in the public area of your job for example :

```js
class NewCustomer implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 5;
```